# How can I set up TestCafe to run on an environment specified in the CLI?

Tags: testing, command-line, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How can I set up TestCafe to run on an environment specified in the CLI?
For example

```
testcafe chrome test.js --env=development
```

I want to set up a list of different environments - such as development, integration, etc - in which I can call in the CLI when running the tests.

Is there a default set-up of this in the config?
Does anyone have an example?

Comment: TestCafe does not provide any support for this scenario.

Comment: It actually does say it can do this on their FAQ page. https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#how-do-i-work-with-configuration-files-and-environment-variables

Comment: TestCafe does not support this functionality out of the box: you need to implement it manually in your test files. For example, it is impossible to set a browser, source code, test run options, etc. using a command line. It is only possible to define values using the documented API. 
If however, you wish to define test URL or global variables, the code from FAQ will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEST_ENV=development npm run test:firefox
```

Above is the command to run test.

Use this environment variable via process.env.Test_ENV, wherever you need to pass 'development' or any other environment as value. The script,

```
 "scripts": {
    "test:firefox": "testcafe firefox ./tests"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple NPM dependency to resolve this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist

```bash
npm install minimist --save-dev
```

Step 1.
In your test file, add the following code:

```js
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

const URL = args.env;
```

Then when running the tests from CLI, add the `--env=your_website_url` flag

== EXAMPLE ==

```js
import minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
const URL = args.env;

fixture('FooterPage Test Suite').page(URL).beforeEach(async (t) => {
    await t.maximizeWindow();
    await t.click(homepageModel.acceptCookie);
});
```

When I run the test:

```bash
npx testcafe tests --env=https://delta-dev.com
```